# If I use "FindControl" outside a UserControl, what do I use within a UserControl?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

Suppose I have javascript within ASP.NET UserControl:

```
function setValue(DataItem) {
    var selectedDate = DataItem.getMember('DomainNameKey').get_object();
    Picker1.setSelectedDate(selectedDate);
}
```

Where Picker1 is also inside the control.  Because Picker1's ID will be renamed at runtime,   what do I put in the code below to make it work within a UserControl?

```
function setValue(DataItem) {
    var selectedDate = DataItem.getMember('DomainNameKey').get_object();
    <%= ?????????????? %>.setSelectedDate(selectedDate);
}
```

Comment: The answer may simply be `Picker1.ClientID`, but it is hard to be certain enough to post as an answer without knowing what type of control Picker 1 is.

Comment: Picker1 is a ComponentArtGridControl.  I just tried ClientID, and it doesn't work... ASP.net says that Picker1 is CS0103: The name 'Picker1' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function setValue(DataItem) {
    var selectedDate = DataItem.getMember('DomainNameKey').get_object();
    document.getElementById("<%= Picker1.ClientID %>").setSelectedDate(selectedDate);
}
```

Comment: Although this should be the right answer... it doesn't work for my darn usercontrol.  I think the UC is creating the control I need dynamically and therefore ASP can't find the dynamic control

Comment: I suppose this is just something I need to finish w/the control vendor

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the ComponentArt controls create a second Javascript object that should be used.  Read more here:

Q10103 - HOWTO: Determining the client ID of Web.UI controls in Master / Content pages
http://www.componentart.com/kb/article.aspx?id=10103

Q10087 - HOWTO: Determining the client ID of Web.UI controls in user controls and templates
http://www.componentart.com/kb/article.aspx?id=10087